# Gradle multi project build not loading project

Tags: java, spring, gradle

The endpoints from the main project are working but I cannot reach endpoints from subproject called backend. Main project has the following structure: apps/main/com/itapp/config. There I have controllers folder, Main.java and ServletInitializer. Backend project has the following structure: backend/src/main/java/com/itapp/backend. There I have controllers folder.

My config:

**settings.gradle:**

```
rootProject.name = 'itapp'

include 'backend'
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
mainClassName = 'com.itapp.config.Main'

sourceSets {
  main {
    java { srcDirs = ['apps/main'] }
    resources { srcDirs = ['apps/main/resources'] }
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation project(":backend")
}

bootJar {
  baseName = 'itapp'
  version = '0.0.1'
}


allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

    group = 'com.itapp'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    sourceCompatibility = '11'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    }


    compileJava {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }

    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }

}
```

I have the following project structure:

```
Root project 'itapp'
\-- Project ':backend'
```

Comment: Can you prodive an error trace. 
And what do you mean by "cannot reach endpoints". Reach class or with an http request ?

Comment: @Ruokki there is no error. When I get 404 when I try to hit the endpoint from backend project

Comment: If this is a http error maybe you should share your java endpoint and/or your project configuration. 
What are your package (Spring scan use package to limit the scan)

Comment: I figured out adding the following line it works: @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.itapp.apps, com.itapp.backend"). I'm new in spring boot. Could you explain scanBasePackages?

Comment: Your question is like someone going to a doctor and offering a self diagnosis that is completely wrong, thus misleading the doctor. What makes you think Gradle has anything to do with your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring scan will look inside all class inside your package looking for @Configuration, @Service, @Component, @Controller....

By default the package is the same as the one from your main application in your case `com.itapp.apps`

So spring will only find controller in com.itapp.apps package. And because your other controller are in `com.itapp.backend` he will not find it.

Adding `com.itapp.backend` to the scan will also add your controller to your context and add the endpoint that you want

You can have more information [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning) with a better explaination

Comment: I see, is this the right way to "import" other modules in the main context? is there another way to do it?

Comment: Yes because package scan from another module can be tricky or unclear. 
You can use @Import{aConfig.class} with aConfig a class with @Configuration. And like the main class this will add the package of aConfig.class into the scan